# A generic construct requires that the type 'IConditionalOperator' have a public default constructor

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I would like to create a hierarchy of types that should implement generic unit tests, using an abstract type as a test fixture. The same pattern works well in C#, but I am facing a compiler error: "A generic construct requires that the type 'IConditionalOperator' have a public default constructor.":

```
   type Color =
      | White = 0xFFFFFF
      | Silver = 0xC0C0C0
      | Gray = 0x808080

   type IConditionalOperator =
      abstract member GetName : Color -> string

   type PatternMatching() =
      interface IConditionalOperator with
         member this.GetName color =
               match color with
               | Color.White -> "White"
               | Color.Silver -> "Silver"
               | Color.Gray -> "Gray"
               | _ -> "None"

   [<AbstractClass>]
   type ConditionalOperatorTest<'T when 'T :> IConditionalOperator and 'T : (new : unit -> 'T)>() =
      member this.ConditionalOperator_ReturnsName(name: string) = None

   type PatternMatchingTest() =
      inherit ConditionalOperatorTest<IConditionalOperator>()
```

The corresponding C# code works, and looks as follows:

```
   public enum Color
   {
      White = 0xFFFFFF,
      Silver = 0xC0C0C0,
      Gray = 0x808080,
   }

   public interface IConditionalOperator
   {
      string GetName(Color color);
   }

   public class IfStatement : IConditionalOperator
   {
      public string GetName(Color color)
      {
         if (color == Color.White)
         {
            return "White";
         }
         else if (color == Color.Silver)
         {
            return "Silver";
         }
         else if (color == Color.Gray)
         {
               return "Gray";
         }
         else
         {
            return "None";
         }
      }
   }

   public abstract class ConditionalOperatorTest<T> where T : IConditionalOperator, new()
   {
      public void ConditionalOperator_ReturnsName(Color color, string name) {}
   }

   public class IfStatementTest : ConditionalOperatorTest<IfStatement> {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've defined `ConditionalOperatorTest<'T>` so that it requires `'T` to have a default constructor, which means that `'T` cannot be an interface. So, instead of specifying `IConditionalOperator` as `'T`, use the concrete `PatternMatching` type instead:

```ml
type PatternMatchingTest() =
    inherit ConditionalOperatorTest<PatternMatching>()
```

With this change in place, the F# version now matches the original C# code: `ConditionalOperatorTest<IfStatement>`